# How to get the next hour from a datetime column in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this :

```
 #   date 
---  ------------------- 
 0   2022-01-01 08:00:00
 1   2022-01-01 08:01:00
 2   2022-01-01 08:52:00
```

My goal is to add a new column that contains a datetime object with the value of the next hour. I looked at the documentation of the [ceil function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html), and it works pretty well in most cases.

### Issue

The problem concerns hours that are perfectly round (like the one at #0) :

```py
df["next"] = (df["date"]).dt.ceil("H")
```

```
 #   date                next
---  ------------------- -------------------
 0   2022-01-01 08:00:00 2022-01-01 08:00:00 <--- wrong, expected 09:00:00
 1   2022-01-01 08:01:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00 <--- correct
 2   2022-01-01 08:52:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00 <--- correct
```

### Sub-optimal solution

I have come up with the following workaround, but I find it really clumsy :

```py
def nextHour(current):
  return pd.date_range(start=current, periods=2, freq="H")[1]

df["next"] = (df["date"]).apply(lambda x: nextHour(x))
```

I have around 1-2 million rows in my dataset and I find this solution extremely slow compared to the native `dt.ceil()`. Is there a better way of doing it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way ceil works, it won't jump to the next hour.

What you want seems more like a [`floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) + 1h using [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
df['next'] = df['date'].dt.floor('H')+pd.Timedelta('1h')
```

output:

```
                 date                next
0 2022-01-01 08:00:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00
1 2022-01-01 08:01:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00
2 2022-01-01 08:52:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00
```

##### difference of bounds behavior between `floor` and `ceil`:

```
                 date                ceil               floor
0 2022-01-01 08:00:00 2022-01-01 08:00:00 2022-01-01 08:00:00
1 2022-01-01 08:01:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00 2022-01-01 08:00:00
2 2022-01-01 08:52:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00 2022-01-01 08:00:00
3 2022-01-01 09:00:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00
4 2022-01-01 09:01:00 2022-01-01 10:00:00 2022-01-01 09:00:00
```